# How to disable the zoom view in the android webview using jquery or meta tags?

Tags: android, jquery, html

Am a php developer and am contructing a website that use in Iphone, Android. The design is ok with Iphone, but in Android its just defaultly zoom out when i loaded the page and can not take my project with this properly. Anyone have any idea about this?

Comment: Are you using webview? Or just viewing your website through any internet application on android mobile?

Comment: Yes. I just viewing site through the browser of Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This meta should do the trick:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Edit:

Try adding these to the code ([source](http://garrows.com/?p=337)):

```
<meta content='True' name='HandheldFriendly' />
<meta content='width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;' name='viewport' />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

Comment: @Seema Sorry then, that's pretty much me fresh out of ideas :(